# Trouble installing pygame on macos

Tags: macos, python, pycharm

I'm trying to get PyGame installed on my 2017 Macbook Pro (10.14.4), but I'm having some difficulty. I'm following the walkthrough [here](https://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/), which is failing at step 8 when I try to run:

```
brew tap homebrew/headonly
```

which I'm assuming means 'headonly' doesn't exist anymore?

I've tried skipping this step and continuing with the installation, but when I try:

```
sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I first get the warning:

*The directory '/Users/willmaclean/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.*

And then a huge error message (which I can attach if anyone wants to go through it). The funny thing is, when I try to import Pygame in PyCharm, it doesn't throw an error at the import line, but it does when I try to use pygame.init(). Can anyone help me?? Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the error on step 8? Saying it fails is not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the extra note for step 8 on that site?

```
(NOTE 18JUL2015: 
Updated to reflect changes to the smpeg library; 
if you have any trouble here, 
try brew install –HEAD smpeg instead, 
with two dashes/hyphens before the HEAD option).
```

Comment: That was the fix! Helps to read the instructions properly :)

Comment: Don't worry, we have all been there! I am glad I could help you out